# join() throws thread_resource_error?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm in a situation where calling `join()` on a `boost::thread` object throws a `thread_resource_error` exception. Looking at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.join) there is no mention of that this method could throw such an exception.

I'm not quite sure where to start debugging this. Any suggestions as to what could cause this?

Comment: You could start by providing us with the code that causes it, and if you've used GDB or another debugger, which line etc.

Comment: I cannot provide a reproducible sample as there is to much code. The code that causes it is the call to `join` when shutting down my application. I'm using visual studio, and don't have the required boost symbols. Thus I am left at guessing possible causes.

Comment: Can you at least give us 3 or 4 lines prior to and after? We've not got much go off of.

Comment: If I provide the 4 lines prior I have to provide a lot of more code to make those lines make sense, so no.

Comment: Figured it out from the boost source code. This exception is only thrown if the thread tries to join itself, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Alright, well. All I could dig up is: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/thread.html#id1709875
and 
"Which means that it couldn't create an instance of a thread resource: a mutex,
a thread, a condvar, etc."

But, that sounds like too many threads being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the boost source code I found the following:

```
void thread::join()
{
    if (this_thread::get_id() == get_id())
    {
        boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error(system::errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur, "boost thread: trying joining itself"));
    }
    detail::thread_data_ptr local_thread_info=(get_thread_info)();
    if(local_thread_info)
    {
        this_thread::interruptible_wait(local_thread_info->thread_handle,detail::timeout::sentinel());
        release_handle();
    }
}
```

So basically it has some undocumented behavior where it throws a `thread_resource_error` if a thread tries to join itself.

Comment: Would it have been possible to obtain that exception text in your program?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, of course, forgot about the what().